# set list of object as dropdown list datasource

Tags: asp.net

I have this method: that returns a list of Category object , and i want to set this list output as Drop down list Datasource in c# , how can i do that

```
public List<Category> GetAllCategories()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectonstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllCategories", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {                  
                    Category cat = new Category();
                    cat.JobCategoryid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["JobCategoryid"]);
                    cat.CategoryName = reader["categoryName"].ToString();
                    Categories.Add(cat);
                }
                reader.Close();
                return Categories;

            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
dropdownList.DataSource = GetAllCategories();
dropdownList.DateTextField= "CategoryName";
dropdownList.DataValueField = "JobCategoryid";
dropdownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks Lcarus, so its simple , I was trying to complicate myself by doing this:  List<Category> list = new List<Category>;
list=GetAllCategories(); ....